# Не снимается звезда при использовании unpin

Tags: дефект, чат

## The message is not unstarred when unpinned

1. Создать чат и воспользоваться кнопкой / Create chat and use button

   > pin this message
2. Воспользоваться кнопкой / Use the button

   > unpin this message
3. Сообщение по-прежнему отмечено звеждой / The message is starred still
4. При попытке снять звезду показывается / When trying to unstar by click get

   > You cannot star your own messages
   > click here to remove the notification bar

Логично, чтобы звезда снималась на шаге 2.
It would'be been logical to unstar the message on step 2.

Comment: не, pin/unpin - только закрепляют :-) тут скорее другой баг - то что прикрепленное даже собственное сообщение можно отметить звездой

Comment: Где вообще эти кнопки?

Comment: @alexolut, https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ReCm.png

Comment: Надо добавить п. "Написать сообщение" м/у 1 и 2.

Comment: И всё-таки @Grundy наверное прав. `pin` только для закрепления. А `unstar` можно сделать только через `cancel stars`.

Comment: @alexolut, ну так unstar тоже не работает...

Comment: Так я и говорю, что `unstar` только через `cancel stars`. Сам `unstar` говорит, что нельзя свои сообщения отзвёздить обратно.

Comment: @alexolut, а где там cancel stars? Не вижу такого.

Comment: Справа где список звездатых сообщений выводится.

Answer (score 2):

На Meta.SE есть [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134858/339911) на подобный вопрос более чем 4х-летней давности.
Для снятия звезды с закрепленного (pinned) сообщения нужно выбрать пункт "cancel stars". Одновременно с этим происходит и открепление (unpin) сообщения.

Простое открепление (unpin this message) не снимает звезды с сообщения.

Таким хитрым образом владелец чат-комнаты может помечать свои собственные сообщения звёздами, что в общем случае (через явную попытку установить звезду) не является возможным.

Замечу, что повторная попытка закрепить сообщение, которые было ранее откреплено, невозможно для владельца комнаты. Может только модератор.

Comment: Но ведь это всё равно баг?

Comment: @Qwertiy баг в наличии обходного пути для установки звезды для своего сообщения, но не в том, что звезда остается при откреплении сообщения.